# creating a nested json output file using jq variables using

Tags: shell, jq

I'm trying to create a json file via shellscript, and someone has mentioned jq, but I'm  struggling a little bit to make it work:
**The desire output is:**

```
inboundurls{
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/support",
  "apiSupports": [
    {
      "familyType": "EXAMPLE",
      "healthCheckUris": "http://example.com"
    }
  ],
  "inboundurls": [
    {
      "healthCheckUris": "http://example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Researching about I found a start point, but it's not working properly, I need some help, here is what I have:

**script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
apiSupports=$(jq -n --arg familyType EXAMPLE \
              --arg healthCheckUris http://example.com \
              '$ARGS.named'
)

final=$(jq -n --arg op "add" \
              --arg path "/supportServices" \
              --argjson apiSupports "[$apiSupports]" \
              '$ARGS.named'
)
echo "$final"
```

**the output of the script above:**

```
{
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/supportServices",
  "apiSupports": [
    {
      "familyType": "EXAMPLE",
      "healthCheckUris": "http://example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

If anyone could help me I would be glad, or even suggesting Ideas, thank you in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following produces the valid JSON component of what is shown as the desired output:

```
jq -n --arg op "add" \
   --arg path "/support" \
   --arg familyType EXAMPLE \
   --arg healthCheckUris http://example.com '
   {$op, $path, 
    apiSupports: [ {$familyType, $healthCheckUris }],
    inboundurls: [ {$healthCheckUris }]
 }
'
```